# What transformation gives a Weyl-like representation by flipping $\gamma^0$ and $\gamma^5$?

Tags: representation-theory, linear-algebra, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra, matrix-elements

The usual Weyl representation of the Dirac matrices is defined like this:
$$\tag{1}\gamma_W^a = T_W \, \gamma^a \, T_W^{-1},$$
where
\begin{align}\tag{2}
T_W &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (1 + \gamma^5 \, \gamma^0),
& T_W^{-1} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (1 - \gamma^5 \, \gamma^0) \equiv T_W^{\dagger}.
\end{align}
We then get a kind of **rotation** in the Dirac matrices space (notice the sign in $\gamma_W^5$):
\begin{align}\tag{3}
\gamma_W^0 &= \gamma^5,
&\gamma_W^i &= \gamma^i,
&\gamma_W^5 &= -\, \gamma^0.
\end{align}
This is the Weyl representation of the Dirac matrices.

Now, I wonder if there's a similar transformation that would perform a *flipping* of $\gamma^0$ and $\gamma^5$, instead of a *rotation* in the $(\gamma^0, \, \gamma^5)$ "plane".  I'm looking for a matrix $V$ (probably unitary) such that
\begin{align}
\gamma_V^0 &= V \, \gamma^0 \, V^{-1} = \gamma^5, \tag{4} \\[1ex]
\gamma_V^i &= V \, \gamma^i \, V^{-1} = \gamma^i, \tag{5} \\[1ex]
\gamma_V^5 &= V \, \gamma^5 \, V^{-1} = \gamma^0. \tag{6}
\end{align}
Is such a transformation possible, using some unitary matrix $V$?  How can we find it explicitely?

Transformations (4) and (6) imply that both $\gamma^0$ and $\gamma^5$ commute with the matrix $V^2 \equiv V \, V$:
\begin{align}\tag{7}
V^2 \, \gamma^0 &= \gamma^0 \, V^2,
& V^2 \, \gamma^5 &= \gamma^5 \, V^2.
\end{align}
My intuition tells me that there's no unitary matrix $V$ satisfying (4)-(6), but I'm probably wrong.  The sign in (3) pisses me off!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, you are doomed. There is no such *V*.

Suppose there were an equivalence (4,5,6).

Then consider $\gamma_5 = i \gamma_0 \gamma_1 \gamma_2 \gamma_3$, as well as its transform, independently of basis or representation,
$$
V\gamma_5 V^{-1} = i V\gamma_0 \gamma_1 \gamma_2 \gamma_3  V^{-1} \implies \\
\gamma_0 = i \gamma_5 \gamma_1 \gamma_2 \gamma_3 \\ = i \gamma_5 \gamma_0\gamma_0\gamma_1 \gamma_2 \gamma_3= \gamma_5\gamma_0\gamma_5= - \gamma_0.
$$

Comment: Wow!  Excellent demonstration!  Thank you very much, it's a nice one!

Comment: Thanks.    The tensor product rep of the Dirac rep all but leads you to it.

Comment: I think that this demonstration is well worth a notice in a book.  Maybe as an exercice.